# Corona SDK distribution and size of objects

Tags: lua, coronasdk, mobile-development

How to indicate the sizes of objects and their coordinates when developing a mobile game. For buttons, I tried to indicate a percentage of the screen size (local scrPercentW = display.actualContentWidth / 100) or division of a constant display.contentCenterX (display.contentCenterY). But in the simulator on some devices it’s right, but at some intervals and sizes it’s wrong.

For example, I have four buttons on the menu that I need to arrange at the same distance from each other and from the edges of the screen. How should I do it?

Comment: actualContentWidth/100 does not give you a percentage of screen width. this is a matter of basic maths, not programming. your post is off-topic

Comment: I realized that I needed to use display.contentWidth to indicate the location coordinates of objects. And what to use to set the size of graphics or text?

Comment: please refer to the user manual for things like that. if you have some code and you don't get what you expect post it here and ask something

Answer (score 0):

I see that you resolved the problem of display.contentWidth, while for the size of a text you just need this:

```
local someText = display.newText( "here goes your text", 20, 80 )
someText.size = 30
```